Weyl dimension formula and the adjoint representation of G2
I'm having some problems understanding the Weyl dimension formula for G2. From the following post: How to use Weyl dimension formula?
I understand that the Weyl formula for G2 takes the form:
$$\dim V(\lambda) = 1/120 (m_1+1)(m_2+1)(m_1+m_2+2)(m_1+2m_2+3)(m_1+3m_2+4)(2m_1+3m_2+5)$$
where m1 and m2 are the Dynkin coefficients of the representation. However, when calculating the adjoint representation, its highest weight turns out to have the dynkin coefficients (1,0). When using those values in the Weyl formula, it gives a result of dimension 7. However, the adjoint representation of G2 should be of dimension 14. Any clue about what am I doing wrong?

Are you sure? I think i get 14 using your formula as written.

I have calculated it many times and I always get 7. I have made a code for c++ that gives me all the weights and calculates the dimension with the weyl formula, by first obtaining all positive roots, and it always gives me 7. That is why i am very confused about it

The "mistake" is, that $(m_1,m_2)=(1,0)$ is indeed the irreducible $7$-dimensional representation, but not the adjoint representation. This is given by $(m_1,m_2)=(0,1)$ instead, and then the formula gives $14$ as the correct dimension.

I'm sorry, but I have tried what you said and I get that (0,1) is the 7 dimensional representation (?) I have a question that may be my problem. The weights of the simple roots are the rows or the columns of the Cartan matrix?
