Constructing the adjoint representation of G2
I am having some trouble constructing the adjoint representation of the algebra G2. I am trying to get the dynkin coefficients of the representation, but I think I am doing something wrong. The Cartan matrix is the following:
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & -3 \\
-1 & 2
\end{matrix}\right)$$
So I take the simple roots as $\alpha=(2,-3)$ and $\beta=(-1,2)$. Now, by using the root strings I get the following roots: $\alpha+\beta=(1,-1)$, $\alpha+2\beta=(0,1)$, $\alpha+3\beta=(-1,3)$ and $2\alpha+3\beta=(1,0)$. Thus, the dynkin coefficients of the highest weight of the representation should be $(1,0)$. However, using the Weyl dimension formula, the dynkin coefficients of the adjoint representation were supposed to be $(0,1)$. What am I doing wrong?

How do you use Weyl's dimension formula? The highest weight of the adjoint representation of $G_{2}$ is exactly $2\alpha+3\beta$, and $\alpha+2\beta$ is the highest weight of its $7$-dimensional irreducible representation.

I used it like the following post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4909612/weyl-dimension-formula-and-the-adjoint-representation-of-g2 but on that case the dimension obtained is 7 when it should be actually 14

I think you are likely just running into issue over whether you write $G_2$ with the short root on the right or on the left.

Yeah, I think so, but I do not know how to fix it. The formula in that post has been calculated by taking the first root as $(2,-3)$, so I don't really know how to fix it.
